# Preloading some images for listview with UniversalImageLoader

Tags: java, android, android-listview, universal-image-loader

I am using Sergey Tarasevich's library [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) in my Android project to load images into a ListView. At the moment I am loading my pictures in the getView() method in my adapter and everything works as expected.

The problem is I want to load some images (three or four) in advance so that the user doesn't need to wait for the images to load when scrolling. What would be the best approach to achieve this using Universal Image Loader?

Comment: Will this be the same images, again and again? If so, just enable caching, it's closer to the bottom of your URL. Caching is disabled by default - you can enable it so you only take the loading penalty the first time.

Comment: @Ewald Not that simple, I'm afraid. The list is a list of friends with profile pictures. I do, however, cache them, both on disc and in memory, but the problem is that I (down)load them in getView. Wich only get called when the image already should be present to avoid showing the stub.

Comment: Then the only alternative I know if is to do the loading in an AsyncTask - something that runs in the background and that updates the UI as these images become available.

Comment: @Ewald Yes, but that is basically what UIL does.

Comment: That is true - I thought you could spawn it in the background while doing something else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `loadImage(...)` for following images in `getView(...)` to pre-cache them.

Comment: So.. you mean that when I'm at position x in getView I use loadImage on position x+1, x+2 etc?

Comment: Yes, something like that. You can try it, maybe it helps.

Comment: Now using this combined with a listener to preload downwards or upwards. just preloading one give a big boost to the user experience.

Comment: what did you do to preload images? can you post some code that made a change while loading images from universal imageloader

Comment: When scrolling fast and preloading more than one image, ``loadImage()`` gets called multiple times for the same URI. Is your library aware of that and doesn't start loading the same URI concurrently?

Comment: Actually it does but for `displayImage`. If you call `loadImage(...)` multiple times in one moment then you got multiple requests.